# BlackList isn't working when refresh token tries to get access back using JWT (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Please bear in mind that I'll eventually move the blacklist to a cache DB, it's not going to be an attribute in the class, this is just temporary.

This is my full component for the PreProcessorFilter

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RefreshTokenCookiePreProcessorFilter implements Filter {

    private static List<String> blackList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        String authorization = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if ("/tokens/revoke".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getRequestURI()) && nonNull(authorization)) {
            req.getCookies();
            String eliminatedToken = authorization.substring(7);
            blackList.add(eliminatedToken);
        }
        for (Cookie cookie : req.getCookies()) {
            boolean containsTokenEliminado = getBlackList().contains(cookie.getValue());
            if (containsTokenEliminado) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("INVALID TOKEN.");
            }

        }
        if ("/oauth/token".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getRequestURI())
                && "refresh_token".equals(req.getParameter("grant_type"))
                && nonNull(req.getCookies())) {
            for (Cookie cookie : req.getCookies()) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals("refreshToken")) {
                    String refreshToken = cookie.getValue();
                    req = new MyServletRequestWrapper(req, refreshToken);
                }
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(req, servletResponse);
    }

    static class MyServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private String refreshToken;

        MyServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String refreshToken) {
            super(request);
            this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            ParameterMap<String, String[]> map = new ParameterMap<>(getRequest().getParameterMap());
            map.put("refresh_token", new String[]{refreshToken});
            map.setLocked(true);
            return map;
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getBlackList() {
        return blackList;
    }
}
```

It correctly adds the Authorization token to the blacklist, but then I face two problems:

The logout doesn't send the refreshToken, and for some reason the refreshToken is different from the Authorization token (Or maybe it's changing AFTER I put it in blacklist? Not sure but I don't think that's the case, but I could be wrong), and obviously after I log out if I try to go in using the same tokens from client side, it'll only send the refresh token (since the Authorization one was killed properly).

To sum it up:

- When logout, I don't have the refreshToken
- When trying to login with old token, I don't have the Authorization one.

Because of that, Blacklist isn't doing it's proper job, since the 2 tokens are different when it tries to login again...

Any help is appreciated, much thanks.